# Subnetting Difficulty

Tags: networking, broadcast, hosts, subnet

Since I don't have enough rep I posted the images here: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hufP.jpg) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g60ns.jpg)

Hello, taking the following example shown in the first image, Why my teacher has assigned in the solution(image 2) for network one (N1): 7+2 hosts? shouldn't it be 6+2 since the number of hosts in that network is 6 and the first and the last(broadcast) can't be assigned?

He has done the same things until N6 and N7 where he assigned 2+2 for the link.

Is this correct and there should be something that I need to know?

Thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; this might be on-topic at [SU]

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right because from `129:134` its available hosts and from `128:136` 128 `Network Address` and 136 is a `Broadcast Address` so `N1=6+2`.